# How Does void Work With Type Aliassing?

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, type-alias

I've been carefully reading over the rules for type aliasing: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing I specifically have a question about the last rule, wherein we are allowed to cast to:

> `char` or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of `unsigned char`

I've noted that this does *not* include the `void` type. Shouldn't we be able to cast anything to `void` and back too?

Comment: You can cast to `void*` and back.

Comment: Casting a pointer to an unrelated type is not prohibited. Dereferencing the result and using the value is.

Comment: I apologize if my answer sounds condescending. You clearly have more knowledge of c++ than I do, but I want to make sure the answer is understood by anyone who reads it, so I dumbed things down a bit.

Comment: Aliasing is not about what you cast to and from. It's about "examination of the object representation". That is, *dereferencing* the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no type aliasing in that case, because you can't examine an object through a `void*`. To do so, you'd have to dereference the `void*`, but that is disallowed. `void` in any context is an incomplete type, and you can't dereference pointers to incomplete types.

Answer (score 2):

`void` is an incomplete type. There cannot ever be an object of type `void`.

Comment: It's not just incomplete, but it can also never be completed. That's unlike, say, `int[]`, which can certainly be the type of a glvalue (but not a prvalue).

Answer (score 0):

`void` is strange in that you can declare something `void*`, but you would rarely use `void` by itself outside the context of a function definition. In that sense it's an incomplete type, and thus has no real meaning by itself. `void` really just exists for syntax.

You can technically cast a type to `void`,

```
int i = 0;
(void)i;
```

but this is really a no-op. You might see this when someone is trying to hide compiler warnings about unused variables. You can't cast the result back to its original type because it doesn't yield a result.

You can also cast to and declare pointers as `void*`, which means it could a pointer to anything (with some exceptions). However, you can't dereference it until you cast it to complete type, like an `unsigned char`.